# I'm having trouble importing ThreadedWebsocketManager in Python

Tags: python, binance

I trying to import the Binance library :

```
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebscocketManager
```

and received this error:

> Message=cannot import name 'ThreadedWebscocketManager' from
> 'binance.streams'

Does anyone have a fix for this error?

Answer (score 1):

ThreadedWebsocketManager is not part of websockets streams module it can be imported directly from binance:

`from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager`

Refer the [documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html)